# mutate_at with two sets of variables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I just asked [a question about generating multiple columns at once with `dplyr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098345/generating-multiple-columns-at-once-with-dplyr), and I'm a bonehead and oversimplified the problem and have another question. I'd like to find a `dplyr` method for dynamically generating columns based on other columns.

```
  cols <- c("x", "y")
  foo <- c("a", "b")
  bar <- c("c", "d")
  df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 10, d = 20)
  df[cols] <- df[foo] * df[bar]
```

In my first iteration of the question, I included only one set of previously defined columns, so the following worked:

```
df %>%
 mutate_at(vars(foo), list(new = ~ . * 5)) %>% 
 rename_at(vars(matches('new')), ~ c('x', 'y'))
```

However, as the first few lines of code suggest, I would like to instead multiply two existing columns together, and am unable to figure out how to do this. I have tried:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(c(vars(foo), vars(bar)), 
            function(x,y) {x * y})
```

which returns the error:

```
Error in (function (x, y)  : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Is it possible to reference multiple sets of columns to be used on each other with `mutate_at`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as you want to work with two columns, I think `purrr::map2` is the function to work with:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(foo, bar, ~ df[[.x]] * df[[.y]]) %>% 
  set_names(cols) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)

#>   a b  c  d  x  y
#> 1 1 2 10 20 10 40
```

Comment: You can do this  ```df %>% 
  mutate(new = list(map2(foo, bar, ~ df[[.x]] * df[[.y]])))``` but then you need to `unnest` and then convert long to wide which sounds like more hassle than needed.

Comment: You can use map2_dbl: `df %>% mutate(new = map2_dbl(foo, bar, ~ df[[.x]] * df[[.y]]))`

Comment: @WojciechKsiążek ```Error: Column `new` must be length 1 (the number of rows), not 2```